# tensorflow understanding "ssd_mobilenet_v1_pets.config"

Tags: python, tensorflow, config, object-detection, training-data

https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/samples/configs/ssd_mobilenet_v1_pets.config

the following config file is used by ssd model trainer to train custom objects, I would like to get a detailed understanding of each parameters being set as during training my PC lags and kills trainig it is an Corei7 6th gen with 8GB ram.

So I would like to get a better understanding thus allowing me to tweak the parameters and complete training.

**This is my first stackoverflow post so please mention any shortcoming in my question**

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example .. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I think Zunair needs to fine-tune the parameters of the mobilenet config file. Am I right?

Answer (score 1):

Can you put what exactly error you got?
In my case reducing batch size worked for me.
For some basic details, you can refer [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/configuring_jobs.md)  instruction by tensorflow.

[This](https://github.com/Akshaypatil15/object-detection-flowers/blob/master/data/ssd_inception_v2_coco.config) is my customised config file.